# Javascript/JQuery resize textarea with div/"grippie"

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, textarea, resizegrip

I've look at many things covering how to make a "grippie" that resizes a `textarea`, and have tried all the code but none was worked. Any help? I'm trying to make it like the one on Stack Overflow when you ask a question or post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it!! [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/khzuLxxf/12/) is a fiddle with the project. I will continue to update it and make it better!

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="grippie" draggable="false"></div>
```

**QJuery/JavaScript**

```
var resize = false;
$('#textarea').hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    resize = false;
});
$('#grippie').mousemove(function(e){
    if(resize == true){
      $('#textarea').height(e.pageY-18);
   }
});
$('#grippie').mousedown(function(e){
    resize = false;
   resize = true;
});
$(window).mouseup(function(e){
   resize = false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#textarea {
   padding: 2px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   min-height: 50px;
   overflow: auto;
   resize: none;
}
#grippie {
   display: block;
   width: 404px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: #CCC;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   cursor: s-resize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Controlling Stacking on Webpage](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/z-index-property-how-to-control-stacking-in-your-pages/) 
 
You have two divs

```
<div id="div1" class="bottom-layer"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div id="div2" class="top-layer"><img id="grippie" src="grippie.png"  draggable="true"  class="grippie-thingy"/></div>
```

Using ondragstart wire up the of grippie

$('#grippie').on('dragstart', function(evt) {

})

If the user clicks the top-layer and not the grippie setfocus on the textarea

Comment: But what code would I use to resize the `textarea`?

Comment: I don't get what you mean about stacking. I know what `z-index` is and how to use it, but why would I need to?

Comment: You need grippie to hover over your textarea.   You can just have it hover over the textarea in blank space becuase it wouldn't stay in place whever the window is resized or scrolled.  It'd be a nightmare to control it with javascript.  The easiest way to accomplish this is have two equally sized layers stacked on top of each over.  The grippie would be absolutely positioned inside of the top-layer.  The bottom-layer resizes and moves with the top-layer.  The grippie maintains it's position within the top-layer.

Comment: I Don't understand.