# Styling the resize grabber of textarea StackOverflow style

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

We all know the [default textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) in HTML:

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

The default **resize grabber** looks like this:

[image: textarea-resizer-normal]

If we make it **vertically resizable only**, it looks the same.
That is misleading since its style suggests that it is resizable in any direction while it really is not.
Using [bootstrap textareas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#form-controls) also does not facilitate changing the resizer style.

StackOverflow itself has a decent vertical resize grabber which looks like this:

[image: textarea-resizer-stackoverflow]

**How to implement a resize grabber of the StackOverflow kind?**

I am unable to extract this style from the [primary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/primary.css?v=e837779ba1fe) and the [secondary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/secondary.css?v=daf6c76dcc6b) stylesheet (styles from the Meta-StackExchange).
However, they may be a good starting point to figure out an answer to this.

---

### Related:

- Styling the resize grabber (Question): [Can I style the resize grabber of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13126917/12787264)

Comment: inspect the code of SO to notice that it's a simple div

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736223/javascript-jquery-resize-textarea-with-div-grippie

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Thanks, I'll check it out